# Find most common key, value pairs with Hstore in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, hstore

I am collecting a list of items and version numbers in an hstore column in postgres. I'm interested in seeing 100 most common key value pairs. For example if this was my data set:

`"foo"=> "22",

"foo"=> "33",

"bar"=> "55",

"baz"=> "77",

"foo"=> "22"`

I would want to know that `"foo"=>"22"` is the most common key/value pair in my database. Let's say for ease of talking about the problem that the table name is `widgets` and the hstore column name is `items`.

```
select ??? from widgets;
```

Is it possible to get a list of the top key value pairs using only SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, this is pretty easy. Here:

```
SELECT key, count(*) FROM
  (SELECT (each(h)).key FROM reports) 
    AS stat
GROUP BY key
ORDER BY count DESC, key
LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

To get key/value pairs as a set, the relevant function is `each()`:

```
select * from each('a=>1,b=>2')
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE

A simple count with a limit can do the trick:

```
SELECT (item).key, (item).value, count(*) as count
FROM (SELECT each(items) as item FROM widgets) as t
GROUP BY (item).key
ORDER BY 2 DESC, (item).value
LIMIT 100
```

If you're only interested in the keys, you can use the simpler `skeys()` instead:

```
SELECT k, count(*) as count
FROM (SELECT skeys(items) as k FROM widgets) as t
GROUP BY k
ORDER BY 2 DESC, k
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are after the complete key/value pair, the following should do it:

```
select items, count(*) as cnt
from widgets
group by items
order by 2 desc
limit 100
```